# __resolveType returning empty objects

Tags: graphql, apollo

I'm trying to implement form validation using graphql. For some reason when I run this query:

```
mutation validateForm($input: ValidateFormInput!) {
    test: validateForm(
       input: $input
    ) {
        id
        fieldValidations {
            ... on FailedValidation {
                id
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

and there is one field validation with not errors('SuccessfullValidation') it returns {id:'some-id',fieldValidations:[{}]} when it should be returning {id:'some-id',fieldValidations:[]}. This especially doesn't make any sense to me because ID is marked as non nullable field in both fields however I don't receive any errors.

**Resolvers**

```
FieldValidation: {
    __resolveType(obj: any) {
        if (obj.error || (obj._doc && obj._doc.error)) {
            return 'FailedValidation';
        }
        return 'SuccessfullValidation';
    },
}
```

**Type definitions**

```
type SuccessfullValidation {
    id: ID!

    filter: Filter!
    field: Field!
}

type TestError {
    hint: String!
    details: String!
}

type FailedValidation {
    id: ID!

    filter: Filter!
    field: Field!
    error: TestError
}

union FieldValidation = SuccessfullValidation | FailedValidation

extend type Query {
    getFieldValidations: [FieldValidation!]!
}

type FormValidation {
    id: ID!
    fieldValidations: [FieldValidation!]!
}

input ValidateFormInputFields {
    id: String!
    value: String! 
}

input ValidateFormInput {
    fields: [ValidateFormInputFields!]!
    userId: Int!
}


extend type Mutation {
    validateForm(input: ValidateFormInput!): FormValidation!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. From the [spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Inline-Fragments):

> Fragments can be defined inline within a selection set. This is done to conditionally include fields based on their runtime type.

Type conditions (i.e. `on FailedValidation`) are just a way to filter what *fields* are resolved based on the runtime type. They are not a way to filter the actual list of results -- there is no built-in filtering in GraphQL.

If you want to filter the list of `FieldValidation`s returned by the `fieldValidations`, you'll need to add some kind of argument to the field and then implement the appropriate resolver logic.

As an aside, you won't see a validation error for a non-null field being null unless that field is actually requested and it resolves to null. In this case, your type condition on the inline fragment resulted in effectively an empty selection set -- from GraphQL's perspective, the `id` field was not requested, and so it doesn't do a null check for it.